# Blocking User In instagram in ios using ApI

Tags: ios

i  want to block using instagram API in my ios application i used following api
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1574083/relationship?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN but i got output

```
data =     {
    "incoming_status" = none;
    "outgoing_status" = none;
    "target_user_is_private" = 0;
};
meta =     {
    code = 200;
};
```

but user  is not blocked

Answer (score 2):

Are you actually passing in the action?

Your request should look like this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1574083/relationship?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&action=block
```

Notice the second parameter `action=block`

as per the API documentation:

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/